# Is Truecrypt/Macfuse supported on Snow Leopard with 64-bit kernel?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit, truecrypt

TC runs, but I get this error when trying to mount a volume:

> Failed to load
>   /Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext
>   - (libkern/kext) link error.

I've seen various posts talking about 64-bit support for both TC and MF, but nothing conclusive.  I'm running TC v6.3 and MF v2.0.3.  Anyone know if this combo works without having to recompile TC from scratch?

Comment: This worked for me. http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2011/04/18/fixing-macfuse-latest-os-x-kernel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of MacFuse 2.0, the entire stack is [available in 64-bit](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/CHANGELOG).  Not sure about TrueCrypt, but you don't seem to be getting that far anyhow, probably because the default MacFuse build is broken.  You can download a [hopefully fixed](http://groups.google.com/group/macfuse/msg/f7de55623e8b8f57?) 64-bit MacFuse at http://static.caurea.org/MacFUSE/MacFUSE-2.1.7.dmg

Comment: Wow, that did it!  It still relaunches system preferences in 32-bit mode, but the app works now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The caurea re-compile has a bunch of locking issues and you will end up with corrupt data. The Tuxera 2.1.9 version supposedly has these locking issues fixed but it is in beta. I haven't been able to find anyone reporting any issues, but that doesn't mean there aren't any.

You can find up-to-date information, including a compiled version of the Tuxera binary here:

http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2010/12/31/macfuse-for-64-bit-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. The kext needs to be re-written to work and as of yet no one has done it. Here's an explanation from the original developer for MacFuse [Some Answers - Amit Singh](http://groups.google.com/group/macfuse/browse_thread/thread/97951b355e57db56)

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should paraphrase or quote the site, and then link the site as the source